# How to run multiple feature files sequentially in Cucumber Webdriver IO

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd, webdriver-io, wdio

I have 3 feature files and corresponding Step definition files . How can I run these feature files one after the other in Cucumber WEBDRIVER IO. I am using VS Code.

Comment: In wdio config file I tried giving the path of all feature files. But shows some error.
 specs:` [
        './features/TC001_Login.feature'

        ],
        [
        './features/TC002_Home.feature'

        ],

cucumberOpts: {
               // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
               require: ['./features/step-definitions/TC001_steps.js'],
               require: ['./features/step-definitions/Home_steps.js']
               }